# MUI DatePicker - How can I change YearPicker styling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was just trying out DesktopDatePicker component and experimenting a bit with it's costumization and noticed I couldn't find any information on how to style YearPicker from DesktopDatePicker.

To costumize PickersDay, for instance, I can use renderDay prop and render a StyledPickersDay.
However for YearPicker, I don't see a renderYear or anything similar :/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNMzT.png)

For context, I wanted to change the color from blue to orange
Is there a different way to do this or it just hasn't been implemented yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the CSS in the `YearPicker` component: https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/year-picker/#css